# Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is equivalent to the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I'm attempting to teach myself topology for graduate school this summer, but I'm having a tough time. 
I'm trying to prove that the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is equivalent to the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$. I realize to do this that I should make a homeomorphism between them, and the identity function would work for this, but I'm unsure on what to do from there.

Here's what I have so far: 
Let $x \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ be some open set in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, then there exists an open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq U$. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

I have read this [Product topology and standard euclidean topology over $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755586/product-topology-and-standard-euclidean-topology-over-mathbbrn-are-equival) but I do not understand why you are allowed to assume that each of the subsets in $B^1_{\epsilon}(x_i)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$. thank you

Comment: Use that if $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_{m+n})\in U$ and $U$ is open, then there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $(x_1-\epsilon,x_1+\epsilon)\times \cdots \times (x_{m+n}-\epsilon,x_{m+n}+\epsilon)\subset U.$

Comment: try to show that the identity map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: mfl- that makes sense by the way the euclidean metric is defined, but what guarantees that each of these intervals is open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint* Suppose  $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ are the Euclidean norms in $ \Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m$ respectively. Then $\lVert (x,y)\rVert = (\lVert x\rVert_1^2+\lVert y\rVert_2^2)^{1/2}$ is the Euclidean norm in $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: Okay so for $x = (x_1,...,x_m,x_{m+1},...x_{m+n})$ and $y$ being of the same form, then the distance $d$ w.r.t. the euclidean metric would be $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n+m} (x_i - y_i)$ and let $xm=(x_1,...,x_m),xn=(x_{m+1},...,x_{m+n})$ and same for $y$, then $d(x,y) = \sqrt{ (d(xm,ym)^2 + d(xn,yn)^2}$ But I'm not really sure how this helps

Comment: Ohhh never mind, I get it

Answer (score 0):

Just use $f:\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{m+n}$. $((x_1,...,x_m),(x_{m+1},...,x_{m+n}))\to (x_1,...,x_{m+n})$ Now see that it is bijective and continuous. Actually it some kind of identity function. [As you are having problem, some things you need to clarify,
1) Eucledean topology is same as the metric topology, here euclidean norm is the metric,$d(x,y)=||x-y||$ (check!!)
2) For finite products, box topology is same as product topology. I don't know whether you come across the term box topology or not, but advise you to make your conception clear in these cases]

Comment: may i know why this is credited $-1$??